# HMAC-SHA1 signing without external libraries (eg CryptoJS)

Tags: javascript, twitter, hmac

I need to encrypt then base64 encode a string to authenticate with Twitter's OAuth 1.1 API.

The platform I'm designing for provides an HMAC function so that first part is fine. However, when I try to Base64 encode the result, it's encoding the hex representation and not the bytecode version of the HMAC hashed output.

My working example uses CryptoJS but I need to achieve the same result without it, but using `btoa` gives a different result.

**Current working code, using CryptoJS for the HMAC then Base64 encoding:**

```
const encrypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("message", "secret");
const encoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted)
console.log(encrypted);
// encrypted = "0caf649feee4953d87bf903ac1176c45e028df16"
console.log(encoded);
// encoded = DK9kn+7klT2Hv5A6wRdsReAo3xY=
```

I've been able to debug by duplicating the code within Python (my preferred language) and can see that the 'encrypted' version is a hexadecimal string, which is why the 'built in' version I've tried doesn't work.

EDIT: Added code for `btoa`, which gives the wrong output for what I need. Compare with output above for `encoded`:

```
console.log(btoa(encrypted));
// btoa_version = "MGNhZjY0OWZlZWU0OTUzZDg3YmY5MDNhYzExNzZjNDVlMDI4ZGYxNg=="
```

Comment: You'll need to implement your own HMAC-SHA1 code then.

Comment: you can use `btoa` and `atob` to convert to and from base64.